# checkbox form validation - jquery

Tags: html, jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#update2').click(function(){
     var checkboxes = $('input[name="checkbox1"], input[name="checkbox2"]');
     checkboxes.on("change", function(e){
        checkboxes[0].setCustomValidity(checkboxes.filter(":checked").length ? '' : 'please select at least one option to procees')
     }).change
  });
});


$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#select2').click(function(){
     var checkboxes2 = $('input[name="choose1"], input[name="choose2"]');
     checkboxes2.on("change", function(e){
        checkboxes2[0].setCustomValidity(checkboxes2.filter(":checked").length ? '' : 'please select at least one option to procees')
     }).change
  });
});
```

```html
<form>
 <input type="radio" id="update" name="update-button" value="1">
 <input type="radio" id="update2" name"update-button" value="2">
 
 <input type="checkbox" id="check1" name="checkbox1" value="3">
 <input type="checkbox" id="check2" name="checkbox2" value="4">
 
 <input type="submit" name="submit-button">
</form>

<form>
 <input type="radio" id="select" name="select-button" value="10">
 <input type="radio" id="select2" name"select-button" value="11">
 
 <input type="checkbox" id="box1" name="choose1" value="12">
 <input type="checkbox" id="box2" name="choose2" value="13">
 
 <input type="submit" name="submit-select">
</form>
```

Im trying to set custom validation to the checkboxes. so when i select the radio button with the id "select2", the checkboxes with diffrent name "choose1" and "choose2" one of them is required before submitting the form. it is working perfieclty in the first example with "update2" and "checkbox1","checkbox2" checkboxes. but i have no idea why it is not working in the second example with the "select2" and "choose1", "choose2" checkboxes.

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): Introduce the problem first before you post any code.

Comment: What do you expect `}).change` to do?

Comment: You are binding a new change event every time you click on your select2 or update2, this means if you clicked on it 6 times, and then your checkbox changed, you would fire your event 6 times.  Move your change binding outside your click and just call `checkboxes2.change()` inside the click

Comment: I agree with Pete and what is `.setCustomValidity` function? can you validate form for each radio button select and then respective checkboxes?